# Making a python script play audio without the script pausing

Tags: python

I know how to make a python script play audio, but how do I make the script continue right after playing the audio?

For example, in this python script example

```py
line1
line2
line3
playsound('track.mp3')
line4
etc...
```

But, when it goes to playingaudioline, it waits for the audio to end, before continuing on to the other lines. How do I force it to continue into the script without waiting for the audio to end?

I've tried separating the audio script and the main script into two, but that didn't work.
This is my python script, assisted by enzo.

```
from win32gui import *
from win32api import *
from win32ui import *
from win32con import *
from random import *
from playsound import playsound

desk = GetDC(0)
x = GetSystemMetrics(0)
y = GetSystemMetrics(1)
w = GetSystemMetrics(0)
h = GetSystemMetrics(1)
sw = GetSystemMetrics(0)
sh = GetSystemMetrics(1)
a = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)
b = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)

thread = threading.Thread(
    target=playsound,
    args=('/Users/mrlee/Downloads/track2.mp3',),
)

thread.start()
for i in range(0, 100000):
    brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(
        randrange(255),
        randrange(255),
        randrange(255),
    ))
    PatBlt(desk, 0, 0, x, y, PATINVERT)
    PatBlt(desk,randrange(x),randrange(y),randrange(x),randrange(y),PATINVERT)
    BitBlt(desk,10,10,w,h,desk,12,12,SRCAND)
    StretchBlt(desk, -20, -20, sw+40, sh+40, desk, 0, 0, sw, sh, 0x9999999)
    StretchBlt(GetDC(NULL), 50, 50, a - 100, b - 100, GetDC(NULL), 0, 0, a, b, SRCINVERT)
    DeleteObject(brush)
    Sleep(0)
thread.join()
```

Thanks to enzo, I got it successfully working.

Comment: Try looking at [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) or [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). They support concurrent code.

Comment: @enzo Do you think its possible if you can maybe do an example with the line1 line 2 thing I put?

Comment: Yes, I will explain it better in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a function named `playsound` that plays an audio for 1 second. Here, I will represent it using a delay:

```py
import time
def playsound():
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Sound played!')
```

Using the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) library:

```py
import threading

thread = threading.Thread(target=playsound)
    
print('Line 1')
print('Line 2')
thread.start()    # The sound is triggered to play
print('Line 3')
print('Line 4')

thread.join()
# After all the lines are executed, wait for the sound to be completed
```

This will output

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Sound played!
```

Note that the code above will not wait one second between lines 2 and 3. Instead, it'll play the audio concurrently.

---

In the context of your question:

```py
import threading

thread = threading.Thread(
    target=playsound,
    args=('/Users/mrlee/Downloads/track2.mp3',),
)

thread.start()
for i in range(0, 100000):
   (gdi script)

thread.join()
```

Comment: Quick question, how do I do that code thing so i can post my python code, because my audio is (also) 2:22 long.

Comment: My code is using "for i in range(1, 100000):" thing at the bottom, but I want the audio to play while the loop is also working.

Comment: Take a look at [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/9997212). You can edit your question.

Comment: I have edited my question, as well as the code. The audio I'm playing lasts 2 minutes and 22 seconds.

Comment: I have edited my answer, see if it solves your problem.

Comment: I have copied and added it into my script properly, but it doesnt seem to have worked. I have used from threading import * to match with the other imports, and but the thread = in it aswell. In the audio part, is there meant to be a ,),?

Comment: I have put all of the pieces of things inside of the code, but it still doesn't work!

Comment: Yes, it's meant to be that way, since it's expecting a tuple of arguments. What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is there an error or the audio is still hanging? If you can, edit your question again with the updated code.

Comment: Sadly it doesnt tell me when theres an error, it just closes. Audio doesn't play either. the python window just closes

Comment: Try to open your command prompt and run the program with `python <name-of-your-file>.py`, it will show if you're having any errors. Other than that, without your updated code, I can't help more.

Comment: Apparently it says threading is not defined?

Comment: Despite there being "from threading import *" in the FIRST line of the script.

Comment: `import threading` and `from threading import *` do different things. If you use the former, use `threading.Thread` when creating the `thread` variable. If you use the latter, use only `Thread` when creating it.

Comment: ok i changed it to import threading and it worked! thank you so much!

Comment: It has worked, but i have another question. How would you make it so that it does the same but for opening another python file? @enzo